# How to use CDI field injection in Quarkus in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, cdi, inject, quarkus

I'd like to inject beans a Kotlin field in Quarkus. The sample file looks like

```kotlin
package org.example

import com.google.inject.Inject
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path

@Path("injectDemo")
open class InjectDemo @Inject constructor(val bm1: BeanManager) {

    @field:Inject
    protected open lateinit var bm2: BeanManager

    @GET
    fun demo() {
        println("bm1 $bm1")
        println("bm2 $bm2")
    }
}
```

The constructor parameter injection works fine however field `bm2` remains uninitialized.

Console output:

```
bm1 io.quarkus.arc.impl.BeanManagerImpl@6b7ac97f
2020-05-21 03:45:11,670 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /injectDemo failed, error id: ac118d6b-a26e-47e7-8c10-12e6a96e50ba-3: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bm2 has not been initialized
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:362)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:87)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bm2 has not been initialized
    at org.example.InjectDemo.getBm2(InjectDemo.kt:12)
    at org.example.InjectDemo.demo(InjectDemo.kt:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:621)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:487)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:437)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:362)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:439)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:374)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:67)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:488)
    ... 17 more
```

Is it possible possible to use CDI field injection in Quarkus in Kotlin? If yes, what needs to be set up for injection to work?

I'm running the app from an uberjar, not a native image.

The jar contains generated class org.example.InjectDemo_Bean containing a method `create()` disassembled version of which doesn't show any attempt of inject into `bm2` field:

```java
    public InjectDemo create(CreationalContext var1) {
        Object var2 = this.injectProviderSupplier1.get();
        CreationalContextImpl var3 = CreationalContextImpl.child((InjectableReferenceProvider)var2, var1);
        Object var4 = ((InjectableReferenceProvider)var2).get((CreationalContext)var3);
        return new InjectDemo((BeanManager)var4);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://quarkus.io/guides/kotlin#cdi-inject-with-kotlin Kotlin annotation reflection miss `Target` annotation which caused injection to fail. The solution is to add field `javax.enterprise.inject.Default` annotation:

```
    @field:Default
    @field:Inject
    protected open lateinit var bm2: BeanManager
```